# How do you get around PHP's DateTime usage of UTC for timestamps?

Tags: php, datetime

The [PHP manual for DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) states

> The $timezone parameter and the
> current timezone are ignored when the
> $time parameter either is a UNIX
> timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or
> specifies a timezone (e.g.
> 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

Which means that when I do

```
$time1 = new DateTime('@'.time());
$time2 = new DateTime();
```

I will have two different results since my default timezone is not UTC. How do you handle this? I don't want to change my server timezone - yet I need timestamps to be output in my timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$time1 = new DateTime(NULL, "<your timezone here>");
```

Or you can specify your preferred format in the first field and leave the timezone NULL.

Comment: The problem is that I often have to pass different timestamps as the value which means that the timezone is ignored.